# Update plus 1 in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, function, foreach

I have a problem with update number
I want update some number few times in foreach and it doesn't work.

When I have in `$ids` two or more values, number (`num_from`) was updated **only one time**. I want this: Every loop in foreach will be update plus one.

```
function o_generate_key($ids)
{
    foreach($ids as $id)
    {
        Core::$db->config->where('name', 'num_from')->update(array(
            'value' =>  Core::config('num_from')+1
        ));
        $num = Core::config('num_from');

        $key = .......

        Core::$db->order()->where('id', $id)->update(array(
        'track_num' => $key
    ));
    }
}
```

`track_num` is same in every id which I selected.

Where I have a problem?
Thanks.